# How Can I change "Add Dashlets" in french in SUGARCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm working on sugarCRM CE 6.5 version.
I changed whole application in french accept 1 button in the home screen.
Please any one can help me.
I would like to change "ADD DASHLETS" button which is located in home screen right side corner.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check The label

```
LBL_ADD_DASHLETS
```

Directory

```
/include/language/fr_fr.lang.php
```

If You have css customization for header ,footer then check your .tpl files

Directory something like

```
/custom/themes/Sugar5/tpls
```

Answer (score 0):

Change label LBL_ADD_DASHLETS in include/language/fr_fr.lang.php

Comment: I took out "ADD" word from English file but doesn't work too there is any other file where I have to change

Comment: I added "'LBL_ADD_DASHLETS' => 'Ajouter Dashlets'," this line in file

Comment: I think my label name is different

Answer (score 0):

Which language pack do you use to translate your SugarCRM in french? 
If you will use this one www.sugarforge.org/projects/francais/ I think that will work without any changing.